# Page last access date

Tags: plugins

When running a very large wordpress based website, we sometimes "collect" a lot of old garbage pages that are not in use anymore.

I am looking for a plugin or a way to add a column to my admin portal which will show me the date and time a certain page/post was accessed by a website user.

Yes, I know we can do this with GGL Analytics, but I think a plugin will be much better.

Comment: If your website is a very large WordPress based site, logging access to each page is going to be a very huge bottleneck too. Have you considered an Ajax action to dynamically read analytics from a third-party website ( like google analytics ) and then add it to the admin column via JavaScript?

Comment: The idea is to log just the last date each page was accessed. Not talking about logging ALL access, just the last access date.